# Azure devOps WebJobs fails after .NET 5 Migration

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, .net-5, kudu

I've got several webjobs that I deploy using an Azure DevOps pipeline. After the .NET 5 migration I have these errors in Kudu

[image]

This happened after .net 5 migration but I don't really think it is connected to it. The app service configuration is set to NET5.

I already try these actions:

1. Manually delete all jobs in kudu and redeploy them
2. Deploy the webjobs in another app service
3. Obviously (ironically) in the local environment it works

The fact that they won't work in another app service means the problem is in the devOps pipeline, but I didn't change it. I mean, it builds in net5 right now, that's all.

Could someone know about this type of error? I never encountered something like this in kudu and It's difficult to even search for a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I know if you have any progress? Did the answer below solve your issue?

Comment: Hi, No it did'0t resolve the issue. We are currently refactoring out code even if it works in our local environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, we developed a brand new application based on .net 5 and we deployed it to a new app service based on .NET 5.

We didn't install anything to the app service, so it wasn't the problem.

I don't really know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

*You can add extension on portal or in `scm` site. After installed `ASP.NET Core 5.0 (x86 and x64) Runtime`,  your issue will be solved.*

**1. On portal.**

[image]

[image]

**2. On `scm` site.**

[image]

Comment: At the end of the day, I revert to .net core 3.1 for now. How could be possible that in a new app service .net5 I need to manually install the runtime? I mean, I set the runtime during the creation phase, it should be there. Another thing, If I go in scm => site extensions there's no core 3.1 runtime installed but it works. How is this possible?

Comment: Azure web app is a sandbox environment, no matter what language program you create, all environments are available by default. However, when we use it, when the program is upgraded from .net core 3.1, sometimes there will be a lack of .net 5.0 runtime. Specifically, you still have a support ticket. My method can help solve the problem in most cases. Rather than I need to answer you can it be impossible.

Comment: Yeah you are correct in an 'upgrade case'. But I created a brand new app service using net5 directly from the creation tab, that's because it's weird :) I will check your solution as soon as this afternoon. Thanks for your support.